# How many ways can a couple be selected out of a party.

Tags: combinatorics

Hi I wounder if I'm thinking correctly about this question:

There are 15 married couples at a party. In how many ways can a man and a women at the party be selected so the two are (a) married with each other (b) not married with each other.

My answer is (a) $$\binom {15} {1}=\frac{15!}{1!(14!)}=15$$ and (b) $$15*15-15=15*14=210$$.

Comment: Recycling is a virtue. However, for the second, one can pick the woman in $15$ ways and for each way can choose a man not married to her in $14$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

(a)
    To select a man there are 15 option but women (his partner) is only 1, so ans. is 15*1=15
(b)
    To select a man there are 15 option but for women (except his partner) there are 15-1=14 options. So ans. is 15*14

Answer (score 1):

These are correct, though you didn’t have to work quite so hard for (a): there are $15$ married couples, so there are $15$ ways to pick a man and a woman who are married. And since, as you saw, there are $15^2$ ways to pick a man and a woman, $15$ of which give you a married couple, there must be $15^2-15=15\cdot14=210$ ways to pick an unmarried couple.

Comment: Wow, again? 30 seconds.

Comment: Hmmm, there's an assumption about the couples and the sex of the respective persons making up the couple. Don't mind me...I'm just in a nit-picky and teasing mode, trying to be difficult! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: There is indeed. But it’s clearly being made, or the problem would be insoluble without further information. I suspect that there are literally hundreds of textbook problems that make that assumption; sadly, it’ll probably be quite a while before that changes.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, it would be more interesting if we had some gay couples.

Comment: I was thinking about that too, is it not possible to give a general answer with some factor x the represent the ratio of gay vs straight marriages.

Answer (score 1):

Part (a) is correct. You just want to select one couple of the fifteen that are present. That's slightly easier. Your answer for part (b) is also correct.